# Android view not covering the entire screen

Tags: android, xml, view, graphics

First of all, I would like to say that I'm a total noob when it comes to android development, but I am experienced with java.

I want to create a simple game on android, so I looked up some information and started creating a basic view class. I have it set to draw a red rectangle, over the entire width and height of the screen. However when I run the application, I don't see an entirely red screen, but a red rectangle with white edges around it. I conclude that the view is not covering the entire screen. The xml in the activity is shown below:

```
<com.zeus.test_002.gameView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" />
```

What do I have to add to expand the view over the entire view?

Kind regards,

Zeus

EDIT: sorry guys, apparantly the basic activity file in android studio generates a selection of paddings around the edges. Thanks for pointing out my mistake ;)

Comment: maybe the parent has some margin

Comment: Post the total XML file, that will be easy to understand what's causing the problem

Comment: I feel stupid... there was indeed padding going on in the activity file. Thanks, though!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I forgot the padding at the top of the android studio activity file. thanks to mohammed to point that out.